# How to create cell arrays dynamically

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I need to create 10 empty cells: `Outlier1, Outlier2,...,Outlier10`, each being a different size. Due to the use of a previously existing loop, I'd like to do something like this:

```
for z=1:10

sprintf('Outlier%d',z)=cell(size(R,2),1);

end
```

Basically, each cell will have a different size due to the fact that `R` changes with `z`. However, if I do this, I receive this error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

Could anyone tell me how to get around this?

Comment: I guessed I figured it out: XX=cell(size(R,2),1);
        eval(sprintf('Outlier%d=XX',z));

Comment: Yes. `eval` would be the way to go here.  Consider either deleting this question, or answering it yourself and accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XX=cell(size(R,2),1); 

eval(sprintf('Outlier%d=XX',z));
```